# Is it possible for Camera2 API to have an option for Landscape capture

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to find a way to capture a photo with Camera2, but with Landscape rotation without enabling the rotation option on my device. So what I am trying to do is to take a photo when is rotated to landscape physically, not using the Auto Rotate mode.So what have done is setted up a **when** function to count up the **windowManager** to every key value from 0 to 3 to have an effect. It doesn't work correctly and making photos in Portrait orientation and no effect. Here is the code:

```
private val ORIENTATIONS = SparseIntArray()

    init
    {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180)
    }

 private fun takePicture() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) {
            return
        }

        //Camera Orientation while taking a photo
        when (windowManager.defaultDisplay.orientation) {
            0 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0) //Portrait
            1 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 90) //Landscape
            2 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 180) //Reverse Portrait
            3 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 270) //Reverse Landscape
        }

        val manager = getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice!!.id)
        var jpegSizes: Array<Size>? = null
        
        jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)
        
        var width = 640
        var height = 480
        if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.isNotEmpty()) { //if it doesn't detect the output saving from the manual sizes
            width = jpegSizes[0].width
            height = jpegSizes[0].height
        }
        val reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1)
        
        val outputSurface: MutableList<Surface> = ArrayList(2)
        outputSurface.add(reader.surface)
        outputSurface.add(Surface(textureView!!.surfaceTexture))
        
        val captureBuilder = cameraDevice!!.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.surface)
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO)
        
        val rotation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS[rotation])
        
        /*val tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
        val ts = tsLong.toString()*/
        //outputDirectory
        file = File("$outputDirectory/${SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis())}.jpg")

        val readerListener = object : OnImageAvailableListener {
            override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader?) {
                var image: Image? = null
                image = reader!!.acquireLatestImage()
                val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
                val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
                buffer[bytes]
                try {
                    save(bytes)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } finally {
                    image?.close()
                }
            }

        }
        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler)
        val captureListener: CaptureCallback = object : CaptureCallback() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
            override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Saved in $file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                try {
                    createCameraPreview()
                } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        cameraDevice!!.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                try {
                    session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler)
                } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {}
        }, mBackgroundHandler)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the solution. So basically within the code there is this:

```
val rotation = windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS[rotation])
```

So the **rotation** variable defines the window manager and uses it within the ***CaptureRequest.Build()***, so instead it's been replaced differently using the **init** all the way to the beginning:

```
when (windowManager.defaultDisplay.orientation) {
            0 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0) //Portrait
            1 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 90) //Landscape
            2 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 180) //Reverse Portrait
            3 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 270) //Reverse Landscape
        }
```

So the finalize the code, it looks like this:

```
private fun takePicture() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) {
            return
        }

        val manager = getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        val characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice!!.id)
        var jpegSizes: Array<Size>? = null
        
        jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)
        
        var width = 640
        var height = 480
        if (jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.isNotEmpty()) { //if it doesn't detect the output saving from the manual sizes
            width = jpegSizes[0].width
            height = jpegSizes[0].height
        }
        val reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1)
        
        val outputSurface: MutableList<Surface> = ArrayList(2)
        outputSurface.add(reader.surface)
        outputSurface.add(Surface(textureView!!.surfaceTexture))
        
        val captureBuilder = cameraDevice!!.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.surface)
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO)

        //Camera Orientation while taking a photo
        when (windowManager.defaultDisplay.orientation) {
            0 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0) //Portrait
            1 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 90) //Landscape
            2 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 180) //Reverse Portrait
            3 -> captureRequestBuilder!!.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 270) //Reverse Landscape
        }
       
        file = File("$outputDirectory/${SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis())}.jpg")

        val readerListener = object : OnImageAvailableListener {
            override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader?) {
                var image: Image? = null
                image = reader!!.acquireLatestImage()
                val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
                val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
                buffer[bytes]
                try {
                    save(bytes)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } finally {
                    image?.close()
                }
            }

        }
        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler)
        val captureListener: CaptureCallback = object : CaptureCallback() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
            override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Saved in $file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                try {
                    createCameraPreview()
                } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        cameraDevice!!.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                try {
                    session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler)
                } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {}
        }, mBackgroundHandler)
    }
```